# Get a value from a variable key in dictionary

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a variable env: prod and I am trying to get the value from a `prod` list for a specific zone.

properties are like below

```yaml
   prod:
      us-west-2a:  xxxxxxxx
      us-west-2b:  xxxxxxxx
      us-east-1a:  xxxxxxxx
      us-east-1b:  xxxxxxxx

- set_fact:
    reg: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_availability_zone }}"

- set_fact:
     detach_volumeid: '{{ vars[env].'reg' }}'
```

I am trying to get the value of `prod` region volume id where `prod` is a variable and `reg` is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

A specific dictionary key can be addressed with the dot (`.`) notation but can also be addressed with the brackets notation `[]`.

When you want to address a key as a variable, you will use the later form.

So given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ vars[env][reg] }}'
      vars:
        env: prod
        reg: us-east-1a
        prod:
          us-west-2a:  xxxxxxxx-w-2a
          us-west-2b:  xxxxxxxx-w-2b
          us-east-1a:  xxxxxxxx-e-1a
          us-east-1b:  xxxxxxxx-e-1b
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "xxxxxxxx-e-1a"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```